# ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input:

Tags: tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, object-detection

I'm trying to fit the following training data into my model:

```
data = np.array(data, dtype="float32") / 255.0
for i in coords_list:
    # print(" 'i' is: ", i)
    for j in i:
        # print(" 'j' is: ", j)
        np.array(j, dtype="float32")

split = train_test_split(data, coords_list, files, test_size=0.10, random_state=42)

(trainImages, testImages) = split[:2]
(trainTargets, testTargets) = split[2:4]
(trainFilenames, testFilenames) = split[4:]
```

Where `data` is a list of images in array format, `coords_list` is a list of lists with tuples containing float numbers, and `files` is a list of strings.
After converting my input data (`data` and `coords_list`) into numpy arrays, I split them in training, validation and test sets. Then they are fitted into the model, running a ValueError that the type of `coords_list` cannot be handled.

[...]

```
_ = model.fit(
    trainImages, trainTargets,
    validation_data=(testImages, testTargets),
    batch_size=6,
    epochs=5,           # 50
    steps_per_epoch=1,  # 500
    verbose=1
)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Alexandros.Oikonomid/OneDrive - Priva/Desktop/Truss_Detection/Trusses_Detection.py", line 210, in <module>
    _ = model.fit(
  File "C:\Users\Alexandros.Oikonomid\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alexandros.Oikonomid\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1049, in fit
    data_handler = data_adapter.DataHandler(
  File "C:\Users\Alexandros.Oikonomid\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1104, in __init__
    adapter_cls = select_data_adapter(x, y)
  File "C:\Users\Alexandros.Oikonomid\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 968, in select_data_adapter
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (<class 'list'> containing values of types {'(<class \'list\'> containing values of types {\'(<class \\\'tuple\\\'> containing values of types {"<class \\\'float\\\'>"})\'})'})
```

Any suggestion on how to solve this error would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your nested loop does not convert `coords_list` to a numpy array. This should solve it.

```
import numpy as np

coords_list = np.array(coords_list, dtype="float32")
split = train_test_split(data, coords_list, files, test_size=0.10, random_state=42)
```